# phpmailer email not received by gmail if sender is yahoo mail

Tags: php, phpmailer, spf

I'm trying to figure out why Gmail doesn't receive emails if the `$mail->From =""` is set with a yahoo account.

```
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->From = "$email"; 
        $mail->FromName = $name;
        $mail->AddAddress($admin_email);
```

Above is a part of my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really supposed to work.

Among other things, GMail likely checks the Sender Policy Framework (SPF) for the sender domain to see whether your mail server is allowed to send from that domain. It's unlikely that Yahoo allows this kind of address spoofing from any server, therefore you fail the basic SPF check.

What I would do in your situation is set a static mail from address, but a dynamic reply-to address.

Comment: Thanks for this confirmation. Updated my source and everything works fine.